# hyperledger for uncentralized database

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to implement a tamper proof uncentralized database of some records. these record are static and they cannot be transferred between participants, i.e, not like some currency or a stock. i just want them to be stored as they are. Identity is an important thing with my project. only certain people can add blocks to the chain, rest of them should be only there to verify the chain. Can i implement a blockchain for this usecase? if it is possible should i use an ethereum chain or hyperledger fabric?

Comment: Fabric is a good option here, in my experience better than Ethereum/Quorum.

Comment: @LazarLukic thanks for the reply, but you haven't answered my first question. can i implement a blockchain network for storing transaction less records? literally every example i come across shows blockchain as network for storing and managing transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your use case which is, certain people, add records and certain query records. A typical normal access control application and the database can solve your issue but,

If you deal with untrusted people and need complete transparency with identity-based access control and equal rights of all participants then hyperledger fabric is best.